# Mapping Enum in Hibernate using XML Configuration

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to map an entity property for an enum column of the table. The configuration is using XML. But whenever I am running the code it is throwing an error while validating.

Following is my mapping -

```
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.employeemanager.pojo.Employee" table="employees">

        <property name="gender">
            <column name="gender" />
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">com.sample.employeemanager.pojo.support.Gender</param>
            </type>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I found this solution through google.

And the error I am getting is as follows:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in employees.employees for column gender. Found: enum, expected: integer
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
    at com.sample.employeemanager.common.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at com.sample.employeemanager.common.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at com.sample.employeemanager.common.EmployeeManager.main(EmployeeManager.java:16)
```

The gender enum looks like below:

```
public enum Gender {
    M, F
}
```

Please note the enum is a separate source file.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add below param inside type tag.

```
<param name="useNamed">true</param>
```

Thnaks,
Amit Kumar